# Message box for getting ratings on number of launch for wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

Recently I have been trying to add a message box that should be popped in some interval of time(ex. ***number of app launch***). This message box can also be hidden permanently from popping out.

Answer (score 0):

The following block of code can be dropped into any existing application and helps provide the above functionality:

***In .xaml page,***

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
x:Class="App.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="800" 
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait"  Orientation="Portrait"
Loaded="PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded"> **//Don't forget to add this code on your xaml page**
```

**In .xaml.cs page,**

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private static bool PerformedRatingPromptCheck = false;
    // Constructor

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!PerformedRatingPromptCheck)
        {
            PerformedRatingPromptCheck = true;

            int numAppLaunches = 0;
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.TryGetValue<int>("Rating_numAppLaunches", out numAppLaunches);

            int numNextRatingPrompt = 0;
            if (!IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.TryGetValue<int>("Rating_numNextRatingPrompt", out numNextRatingPrompt))
            {
                numNextRatingPrompt = 3;
            }

            if (numAppLaunches >= numNextRatingPrompt)
            {
                IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["Rating_numNextRatingPrompt"] = numNextRatingPrompt * 2;

                NotificationBox.ShowAgain("Enjoying the app?",
                        "Would you like to rate this app now, support us?",
                        "Ask me later",
                        false,
                        Surpressed => { },
                        "Rating_MsgPrompt",
                        new NotificationBoxCommand("yes", () => { new MarketplaceReviewTask().Show(); }),
                        new NotificationBoxCommand("no", () => { }));
            }

            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["Rating_numAppLaunches"] = numAppLaunches + 1;
        }
    }
```

Source - [Roybott Blog](http://roybott.com/blog/getting-ratings-for-your-wp7-app.html?lastPage=true&postSubmitted=true)